# Как вывести пагинацию на одной странице для каждой категории товаров в проекте Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7

Есть модель категории:

```
  class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Название товара')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='Категории'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Модель товаров:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Наименование товара')
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Цена товара')
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/', verbose_name='Изображение товара')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Category, verbose_name='Выберите категорию товара')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural='Товары'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Views.py:

```
def catalog(request):
    args={}
    args['head_title'] = Head_title.objects.get()
    args['head'] = Head.objects.get()
    args['menu'] = Menu.objects.all()
    args['button'] = Button.objects.get()
    args['category'] = Category.objects.all()
    product_list_all = Product.objects.all().order_by('-date')
    paginator = Paginator(product_list_all, 9)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        products = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        products = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        products = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    args['product'] = products
    args['akcii'] = Akcii.objects.get()
    args['news'] = News.objects.all().order_by('-date')[:3]
    args['info'] = Info.objects.all()
    args['sitemap_title'] = SiteMap_title.objects.get()
    args['sitemap'] = SiteMap.objects.all()
    args['underlogo'] = Underlogo.objects.get()
    args['underinfo'] = Underinfo.objects.get()
    args['form_title'] = FormTitle.objects.get()
    return render_to_response('catalog.html', args)
```

HTML

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
<!--section.navigation-small-->
<section class="navigation-small">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                  <li><a href="{% url 'home_page' %}">Главная</a></li>
                  <li class="active">О нас</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<!--section.navigation-small end-->
<section class="cotalog">

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

      <div class="leftHandSide btn-group">
          <div class="navBarL">
              <div class="navHeader">
                    <p>Каталог</p>
              </div>

              <ul>
                <li><a class="filter" data-filter=".mix">Все</a></li>
                  {% for item in category %}
                      {% if forloop.counter == 1 %}
                <li><a class="filter" data-filter=".category-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if forloop.counter == 2 %}
                <li><a class="filter" data-filter=".category-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
                      {% if forloop.counter == 3 %}
                <li><a class="filter" data-filter=".category-{{ forloop.counter }}">{{ item.title }}</a></li>
                      {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              </ul>
          </div>
      </div>


    <div class="rightSide">
{% for item in product %}
    {% for object in category %}
        {%  if item.product.title == object.title %}
          <div class="product mix category-{{ forloop.counter }}">
              <img class="product_img" src="{{ item.image.url }}" width="91px" height="109px">
              <p class="title">{{ item.name }}</p>
              <p class="price">{{ item.price }}</p>
              <a class="btn-cotalog">Купить</a>
          </div>
        {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
 <div class="pagination">
            {% if product.has_previous %}
                <a href="?page={{ product.previous_page_number }}">Назад</a>
            {% endif %}
            {% for num in product.paginator.page_range %}
            {% ifequal num product.number %}
                <span class="current"><b>{{ num }}</b></span>
            {% else %}
                <a href="?page={{ num }}"> {{ num }}</a>
            {% endifequal %}
            {% endfor %}
            {% if product.has_next %}
                <a href="?page={{ product.next_page_number }}">Следующая страница</a>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
{% endif %}
    </div>
  </div>

</section>
    {% include 'Main/akcii.html' %}
    {% include 'Main/news.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

Проблема в том что при нажатии на любую из категорий Пагинация срабатывает для всех товаров, а не для каждой категории отдельно.

Comment: У вас href нет на категории, возможно в этом проблема

Answer (score 2):

не вижу передачи аргументов отвечающих за отдельную категорию, есть только GET для страниц

```
def catalog(request)
```

Применяется ко всем товарам без разделения на категории

```
paginator = Paginator(Product.objects.all().order_by('-date'), 9)
```

Поэтому разбитие на страницы работает для всех товаров не зависимо от категории.

Необходимо передать категорию, либо в get либо в

```
def catalog(request, cat_slug)
```

И на основании этого уже фильтровать товары

```
paginator = Paginator(Product.objects.all().filter(product__slug=cat_slug).order_by('-date'), 9)
```